# macOS Ventura screenshot tool like Big Sur: change defaults to be able to draw without having to click twice

Tags: screen-capture, defaults

In macOS Ventura, I can't draw right after taking a screenshot like I used to do on macOS Big Sur. Instead, I've to click the Markup tool:

[image: Screenshot of a screenshot window with the Markup Tool highlighted]

Then I would need to click on either Sketch or Draw tools:

[image: Screenshot a screenshot window with the Sketch and Draw tools highlighted]

On macOS Big Sur, the Draw tool was selected without having to do a single click (I think the latest tool was selected by default when taking a new screenshot).

How can I change the config (if possible) to draw without having to click twice?

I don't see how to do it the [help (man)](https://ss64.com/osx/screencapture.html) or on Google either.